# java diamond operator doesn't compile

Tags: java, diamond-operator

When I try to use the diamond operator as follows:

```
List<DateTimeZone> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

It works perfectly.

However, when I try this:

```
List<DateTimeZone> list = false ? null : new ArrayList<>();
```

It doesn't compile,  messaging: 
"Incompatible types: required List, found ArrayList".

Why is that?

Comment: Does not compile in eclipse or using the javac compiler?

Comment: May be you have custom `List` or `ArrayList` class (not from `java.util` package)

Comment: @Pablo I tested with javac, and the same error appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ternary operator and the diamond operator don't get along very well. You have to specify the type explicitly:

```
List<Date> list = false ? null : new ArrayList<Date>();
```

More info at these related questions:

[Java ternary operator influence on generics type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289320/java-ternary-operator-influence-on-generics-type-inference)

[Compilation error with generics and ternary operator in JDK 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381764/compilation-error-with-generics-and-ternary-operator-in-jdk-7)

Comment: +1, So can we conclude that, conditional operator doesn't work with diamond operator ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ It works, but not in Java 7.

Comment: generics inference is best used with Java8